# how to change the below code to lamba method reference

Tags: lambda, filefilter

Hi below is my logic to get the list of files from the folder path provided , the below snippet is working,
But there are sonar issues to change the code to follow lambda expression with method reference.
any help appreciated.

```
public static File[] getFileName(String folderPath) {
    File[] fileEntry = null;
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    fileEntry = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() { 
      @Override
      public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isFile();
      }
    });
    return fileEntry;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA can do such code optimizations as quick fix.

Lambda form:

```
public static File[] getFileName(String folderPath) {
    File[] fileEntry;
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    fileEntry = folder.listFiles(pathname -> pathname.isFile());
    return fileEntry;
}
```

The shortest form is:

```
public static File[] getFileName(String folderPath) {
    return new File(folderPath).listFiles(File::isFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response tkruse, its really helpful , want to add few comments like   public static File[] getFileName(String folderPath) {
    File[] fileEntry;
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    fileEntry = folder.listFiles(pathname -> pathname.isFile());
    return fileEntry;
} these code will give sonar issues even after converting to lambda expression, have tried that, but the shortest form is more sensible, i feel in respective to sonar coverage.

Comment: sure, first form probably gives you other warnings. Shortest should be free of warnings, else tell us the warnings. If my answer is ok, feel free to click accept button on the left.